# Infinite number of subsequences converging to the same limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(u_n)_n$ be a real sequence. We suppose there exists a strictly increasing function $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $(u_{\phi(n)+k})_n$ converges to the same limit $l$.
Does this necessarily mean that $(u_n)_n$ converges to $l$?
The issue with this problem is that the number of subsequences is infinite, which creates a problem when trying to do the proof using the $\epsilon$-definition, so I wonder if this result is actually false which would surprise because it seems so intuitively true.

Comment: Maybe first try to prove it in this case: for all $k$ the sequence $(u_{n!+k})_n$ converges to $0$.  Find a counterexample where $u_n$ has only values $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\phi(n) = 2^n + 1$ and :
$$a_n = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 &\text{if }n = 2^j \text{ for some } j\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right.$$

Then, for any $k\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{align}
a_{\phi(n) + k } =1 &\Longleftrightarrow \exists j, 2^n+1+k = 2^j \\
\end{align}
For $n$ such that $2^{n-1} > k+1$, this has no solution. Therefore, for a fixed $k$, only a finite number of $n$ have $a_{\phi(n)+k} = 1$ and :
$$\forall k \in\mathbb N, \lim_{n\to \infty }a_{\phi(n)+k}=0$$

while clearly $\lim_{n} a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Very nice answer, but how do we get the condition that for $2^{n-1}>k+1$ there are no solutions?

Comment: Hint : For $i,j$ distinct integers, we have $|2^i - 2^j| \geq 2^{i-1}$.

Comment: Ah OK, thank you!